# Oracle APEX checks authentication each page - why? and can I stop it?

Tags: oracle, performance, authentication, oracle-apex, ntlm

I am troubleshooting performance issue in Oracle APEX 4.2.1 app and using custom NTLM authentication.  I have found in the Oracle APEX debug that the ping against a certain large LDAP/AD group requires 3.8 seconds.  I change to a smaller LDAP/AD group and the time goes down to < 0.5 seconds - which is not nearly as noticeable.

I also see that EVERY page submit/refresh has this delay/authentication step.

Is there anyway to authenticate only once per session?  [This link](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/HTMDB/sec_authentication.htm#HTMDB25766)  states that the authentication happens with each page refresh.  Why?

Any help/insight is appreciated.  Thanks, Hawk

Comment: APEX (or any development environment) would need to validate authentication on every page to prevent you from bypassing the login page and going directly to some other page (by manually entering the URL for example) without needing to log in.  You could amend your authentication so that you send a cookie to the client once they are successfully authenticated and check for that cookie at the top of your custom authentication.  Then you'd only need to do your current process if there wasn't a valid cookie.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the quick response.  I'll dig into creating/checking cookie.  I thought it created/used cookie already, but have not investigated.